# jQuery "push down" list as in Twitter's home page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery list like in Twitter's home page. This means, to have many posts listed, and then, after X seconds, another post is inserted at the top of the list, with an effect, and pushing the rest of them down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly how to do this depends on what you want to add.  As a basic principle, however, you can follow this method:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div>First item</div>
 <div>Second item</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('<div>New item</div>').hide().prependTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    },4000);
});
```

This will add a new div to the top of the container every 4 seconds.  When it is added, it will slide down gradually and will push the existing divs down accordingly.

If you can provide some information about where your data is coming from, I can suggest how you might implement it.

Comment: Well, I'm working on Ruby On Rails. Basically, my info comes from a collection of posts. Please let me know which info you need on this so I can provide it to you.

Comment: Is it AJAX?  What is the structure of your list?  What is the structure of your received data?

Comment: Well, there are two possibilities: 1) to load all the posts into a collection, containing its title, description, author, etc. 2) to dynamically load posts using ajax. I'd need both solutions for different kind of lists the site has.

Comment: For (1), you would base this solely on intervals?  I.e. every `n` seconds, add another div to the list until the whole collection has been added?