# Having difficulty trying to change a JQuery "prepend" to "prependTo"

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, slidedown

I'm using backbone to render a model based on a template.

I have this code in my full app view:

```
this.$("#timesheet-start-placeholder").prepend(view.render().el);
```

I'm trying to get a new model to push down other ones, similarly to Twitter or Facebook posts.

I've looked at [this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926719/jquery-push-down-list-as-in-twitters-home-page) and I'm trying to follow it similarly.

However, I can't do:

```
(view.render().el).prependTo($("#timesheet-start-placeholder"));
```

It doesn't execute.

Can anyone think of a workaround? I also have this to work with in my model view:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I've tried various combinations of `hide(), slideDown(), and fadeIn()`, and can't seem to get what I'd like.

Comment: I think you need to call jQuery on the prepend element. Could you try `$(view.render().el).prependTo("#timesheet-start-placeholder");`

Comment: That's it! Sometimes I wonder how I overlook things. Can I accept an answer somehow?

Comment: Added it as an answer, so you can complete it. Glad it helped ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call jQuery on the prepend element. Could you try `$(view.render().el).prependTo("#timesheet-start-placeholder");`